# How to get and send files from an application to another machine or Windows Explorer but not another application?

Tags: windows, delphi, ftp, delphi-2010, windows-explorer

Sorry if my question is confusing but what I am looking to do is this. I am creating an application that is supposed to send and receive files directly to another machine without having to connect to any other application but the windows explorer on another machine. I know you can write a client and server much like a FTP program, but that's not what I am looking for. An application simply connects to Windows or windows explorer on another machine for sending or receiving files.

I have looked or researched for information online, but not much to look at.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how.

**MORE INFO:**
I want to be able to start my application on a machine and send and receive files automatically from or to another local machine without establishing any direct connection very much like what Microsoft Window does. You open your windows explorer and drag and drop files from or to another machine. Only that I want to do that programmatically within my application. I start my application and simply request or send for specific file at a specific location. The way I have it written now you have to run two different copies of the same program on different machines - one as a server and the other as a client.

**Maybe what I am looking for is a way to get access to the filesystem of another local machine without socket to socket connection.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why couldn't you just open a shared directory on the server and send files to that directory?

Comment: Yes, or create an account on the other machine and log on to it directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "connects to Windows"?

Comment: @EMBarbosa It will be over Local Area Network only.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Umm "connects to Windows" means just that. It makes a connection like say UDP or TCP to another local machine like Windows Explorer to Windows Explorer. You don't make any connection and it is all done in the background.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I want to do that but programmatically.

Comment: @LarsTech Ummm how do you open a shared directory programmatically without making socket to socket connection?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer is not an application that foreign programs can "connect" to. You need to connect to something that will actually be listening for connections. The most direct way would probably be to set up a network share on the server and then use [`WNetAddConnection2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385413.aspx) to connect to that share on the client.